Dask embarrassingly parallel for loop optimization
I am trying to speed up some calculations on a pandas.DataFrame. Around half the time of each iteration is taken up just by creating a copy of the dataframe (it has ~1.5 million rows and 10 columns), is there any way I can skip that or an alternative so that I am still able to replicate results?
NOTE: I am running on a single local machine.
from scipy.stats import norm

def iteration(df, seed):
   dfCopy = df.copy()
   rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
   factor = norm.ppf(rng.uniform())
   factors = norm.ppf(rng.uniform(size=len(dfCopy))
   
   dfCopy["result"] = dfCopy["important"] * factor + dfCopy["important"] * factors
   #  and some more operations involving the dataframe and using factor and factors
   
   return dfCopy.groupby(by="ID").agg({"result": "sum"}).reset_index()


sg = np.random.SeedSequence(112622607388004198928332989692281456100)
seeds = sg.generate_state(10000)

delayed_results = []
for seed in seeds:
    result = dask.delayed(iteration)(df, seed)
    delayed_results.append(result)
results = dask.compute(*delayed_results)

I have tried to create new columns in the dataframe in which the perform the calculations and dropping them afterwards, but it would throw an error because of inserting too many columns. Also I don't think running the operations on a dask.Dataframe makes sense because they are not so complex, the only thing that makes it take a lot of time is the copying of the dataframe and the number of iterations.

EDIT: As suggested by @mdurant, you can avoid creating a copy at all.
from scipy.stats import norm

def iteration(df, seed):
   rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
   factor = norm.ppf(rng.uniform())
   factors = norm.ppf(rng.uniform(size=len(df))
   
   result = df["important"] * factor + df["important"] * factors
   #  and some more operations involving the dataframe and using factor and factors
   
   return result.groupby(by=df["ID"]).sum().reset_index()


sg = np.random.SeedSequence(112622607388004198928332989692281456100)
seeds = sg.generate_state(10000)

delayed_results = []
for seed in seeds:
    result = dask.delayed(iteration)(df, seed)
    delayed_results.append(result)
results = dask.compute(*delayed_results)

I assume your operations are vectorized. This might save you a bit of time, since you are not creating copies but references to the original df, without modifying it.

The problem with this is that I must be doing the operations on the original dataframe, which will not work well with dask embarrassingly parallel. Also this does not solve the problem of creating a copy, which takes time (maybe not half, but still some).

Note that you can do result.groupby(df["ID"]) - without creating the intermediate tmp_df.

I edited my answer to include your suggestion @mdurant.

@bogdmu00, I am not sure I understand the issue properly. Why would the above code not work for you? We are not changing anything in the original dataframe.

I'm not sure if it works with dask, but I would try the following.
Assumption: your dataframe contains only numerical values

put the DataFrame into a multiprocessing.Array - only 1 copy operation (can't be avoided)
in each loop (on multiple cores) read the data from the Array which is thread-safe
data in array can be accessed like normal numpy arrays
return your results via a queue or pipe to avoid manipulating the original data

As the data is stored as a ctypes-array, reading from it very fast.
